# RedirectMatch not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/prospective/deginfo.php?classname=PE&diploma_description=BSc+in+Mathematical+Sciences
```

That I need to redirect to this URL instead:

```
http://www.example.ie/prospective/deginfo.php?classname=PEC&diploma_description=BSc+in+Mathematical+Sciences+with+French+%27Bachelor+Honours+Degree%27
```

I thought I could do the following with a `RedirectMatch` to "catch" everything up to `Bsc` and from there get it to redirect to the URL I want but it is not working :

```
RedirectMatch ^/.*BSc\+in\+Physical\+Education http://www.example.ie/prospective/deginfo.php?classname=PEC&degree_description=BSc+in+Mathematical+Sciences+with+French+%27Bachelor+Honours+Degree%27
```

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong and how to correct please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `RedirectMatch`, it only matches against the URI. You can match against it using mod_rewrite and a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^classname=PE&diploma_description=BSc\+in\+Mathematical\+Sciences$
RewriteRule ^/?prospective/deginfo.php$ /prospective/deginfo.php?classname=PEC&degree_description=BSc+in+Mathematical+Sciences+with+French+'Bachelor+Honours+Degree' [L,R]
```